# wordpress - jQuery doesn't work in plug in, but works everywhere else?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Sorry for the easy question, (hey, easy rep!) but I'm new to PHP as of 1 day.  I have to create a wordpress plugin/widget out of necessity.  I have en queued jquery in my header:

```
  `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>`
```

and created a class intended to be clicked in the plugin.

```
  jQuery('.court').click(function () {
      alert(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
   });
```

Simple stuff and it works if I place the code within the footer (which has nothing else in it but some JQ).  It does NOT work if it's inside the plugin.  Javascript alert('boom'); does work in the plugin.

What am I missing in order to use jquery within the plugin?  I obviously don't want to put it in the footer since it won't be packaged there.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: How do you access the console?  Is it a plug in I need to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have to create a wordpress plugin/widget out of necessity.** Are you writing a Plugin from Scratch? If so; try adding the code below anywhere in your Plugin's Main File:

```
    <?php
        function myPluginScripts() {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-my-plugin', get_site_url() . "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js", array(), '');

            // IN THIS FUNCTION, YOU CAN ADD OTHER JS FILES AS WELL LIKE SO 
            // UNCOMMENT THE LINE BELOW & CHANGE THE VALUES IF YOU NEED TO
            // wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plg-js', 'path/to/my-plg.js', array('jquery'), '');
       }

       add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myPluginScripts');
```

Comment: Yes, creating from scratch.  That doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @spas2k     Fortunately, yes it does work ;-)   So long as you do it correctly... Would you mind(please) posting the part of your Plugin's Main File that contains that code?

Comment: <?php

function myPluginScripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-my-plugin', 'path/to/local/jquery.js', array(), '');

    // IN THIS FUNCTION, YOU CAN ADD OTHER JS FILES AS WELL LIKE SO 
    wp_enqueue_script('my-plg-js', 'path/to/my-plg.js', array('jquery'), '');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myPluginScripts');
?>
<script type="text/css">
    jQuery('.court').click(function () {
        alert(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    });

</script>

Comment: If I enter the jQuery code in the chrome console, then it works.  ... Not without the console command though.  I'm missing something, not sure where.

Comment: @spa2k   There is the Problem... You pasted the code just like that. Comments were provided. You have to change: ` 'path/to/local/jquery.js'` to fit with the exact Location of JQuery on your System or to... `get_site_url() . "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"`

Comment: Thanks I'll play around with it and when I get it working I'll come back to accept your answer.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @spas2k  The code was updated to take that into account, anyway - viel Spass ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and explicitly specify your scripts as havimg a dependency on jquery. Then WordPress will make sure your script is loaded later, thus have the `jQuery` object available.